# Is localStorage preferred place to save Authorization token in hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth-2.0, local-storage, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid mobile app (using HTML, JS and Cordova) for android and iOS primarily

**About App:**

- The user log's into app via Sign-in process , secured by OAUTH 2.0
  authentication.
- The application needs to access protected resources at various
  different places in the app, Hence there is a need to store the auth
  token. This token will be passed as Bearer token in authorization
  header while calling the API's

**Question:**

So, is setting and getting Authorization Token (AT) to/from localStorage preferred approach? Please suggest better alternatives if any.

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` is *not* guaranteed to be persistent (especially on iOS), which can mean that your user has to log in to their app more often than expected.

I would suggest using the keychain instead. You might consider using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-keychain). It's persistent, and intended for storing anything sensitive. Of course, whether or not this is viable for you depends on the platforms you intend on supporting.

Comment: I hope it supports both Android and iOS?